# Order a Table in MySql without sendtime

Tags: mysql

How can I query to find the most recent message in a table, when the values in the column `sendTime` are all null?
I have tried.

```
SELECT `from`
,MAX(column) AS most_recent_message
FROM table
GROUP BY `from`
```

Comment: post your schema and sample of data please

Comment: Mysql rows have no inherent order or secret timestamp; if your time values are null there is no way order by time.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, I have found the send date , it is like this `20151020SOMETEXT`, 2015 -Year, 10-Month, 20-Day, SomeText. Is there a way I can spate the numbers from the text?

Answer (score 1):

if you have an auto increment primary key, then you can find the maximum primary key belongs to which column.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table);
```